# How to ignore a custom spring tenant

Tags: spring, scope

We are having a product when we use custom spring scope - 'tenant'.
It is tightly related with our system architecture.

During the live of the product we decided to drop this scope, but we really wouldn't like  to break the backward compatibility.
Other words we want that existing product implementations to start without error like :

> Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Scope registered for scope 'tenant'

We also don't want to correct any occurrence of the tenant defintion in the spring configuration or in any java class (where  `@Scope("tenant")` occurs).

We managed to ignore the the scope while loading bean definitions by using custom

```
XmlBeanDefinitionReader
```

It seems that we are missing the general concept to filter any bean creation (any BeanDefinition ) and ignore the scope - replace it with Singleton.

Here is the code

Here is the code with overrides the scope :

```
 
new ReaderEventListener()
            {
```

@Override
            public void importProcessed(final ImportDefinition importDefinition)
            {
                //
            }

            @Override
            public void defaultsRegistered(final DefaultsDefinition defaultsDefinition)
            {
                // 
            }

            @Override
            public void componentRegistered(final ComponentDefinition componentDefinition)
            {

                for (final BeanDefinition beanDefinition : componentDefinition.getBeanDefinitions())
                {

                    if ("tenant".equalsIgnoreCase(beanDefinition.getScope()))
                    {
                        beanDefinition.setScope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_SINGLETON);
                        if (LOG.isDebugEnabled())
                        {
                            LOG.debug("Adjusting bean defintion for " + beanDefinition
                                    + " - ignoring tenant scope - please modify it manually to avoid confussion.");
                        }
                    }
                }

                for (final BeanDefinition beanDefinition : componentDefinition.getInnerBeanDefinitions())
                {

                    if ("tenant".equalsIgnoreCase(beanDefinition.getScope()))
                    {
                        beanDefinition.setScope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_SINGLETON);
                        if (LOG.isDebugEnabled())
                        {
                            LOG.debug("Adjusting bean defintion for " + beanDefinition
                                    + " - ignoring tenant scope - please modify it manually to avoid confussion.");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void aliasRegistered(final AliasDefinition aliasDefinition)
            {
                //
            }
        }); <code>

It looks like it is working in the most cases except for such ones :


        
            
                EXACT
                REGEX
                STARTS_WITH
                ENDS_WITH
                CONTAINS
            
        
        
            
                
                
            
        
    

It looks like it is able to change the scope tenant for the wrapping

> org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ListFactoryBean

but not for the underlying beans ....

Thing worth mentioning is that we munually load one by one a files containing bean definitions by our own.

Comment: Here is the code with overrides the scope :

Answer (score 1):

Can you register a tenant scope and implement it as singleton?

```
public class TenantScopeMock implements Scope {
  @Autowired private ApplicationContext appContext;

  public Object get(final String name, final ObjectFactory objectFactory) {
    if (!appContext.containsBean(name))
      ((SingletonBeanRegistry)appContext.getBeanFactory()).registerSingleton(name, objectFactory.getObject());
    return appContext.getBean(name);
  }

  public String getConversationId() {
    return null;
  }

  public void registerDestructionCallback(final String theName, final Runnable callback) {
  }

  public Object resolveContextualObject(String key) {
    return null;
  }

  public Object remove(final String theName) {
    return null;
  }

}
```

and register with:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomScopeConfigurer">
  <property name="scopes">
    <map>
      <entry key="tenant">
        <bean class="mypackage.TenantScopeMock" />
      </entry>
    </map>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: HI thanks for a quick response. Well, this works almost perfectly. But actually I would expect there that this will fallback to SINGLETON.  Other thing is that this scope is not seen in my child web aplication contextes. So it looks like i'm forced to define CustomScopeConfigurer for every web application context separately - not sure why

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I have updated the code. As for re-registering it with child contexts I don't know how to achieve this.

Comment: I did not test this code so it may still require some tweaks but this direction should get you a working solution.